# key error in django form with customer parameter

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following form:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):

    options = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.none(), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        question_id = kwargs.pop('question_id', None)
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if question_id:
            print question_id

            question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
            ts = Option.objects.filter(question = question)
            for t in ts:
                print t.name
            self.fields['options'].queryset = Option.objects.filter(question = question)

    def clean(self):
        print 'in clean'
        #this is the last thing to print before failing
        cleaned_options = self.cleaned_data['options']
        try:
            print cleaned_options
            raise forms.ValidationError('That is not the right answer.  Try again.')
        except:
            return cleaned_options
```

I call it in my view like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        print 'in post'
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, question_id=question.id)
        print '---'
        options = request.POST.getlist('options')
        option = options[0]
        print option
        if form.is_valid():
            print '******'
            print form
        else:
            print '######'
            print form.errors
```

My template looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ form.errors }}
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I get a key error in the template at the line that uses Form:

[image]

It seems the line that throws the error is:

```
cleaned_options = self.cleaned_data['options']
```

Comment: The trace would be useful, since you are not using any form of exceptions yourself. The problem is that probably your queryset is failing, but we can't know with further debugging.

Comment: @petkostas  the queryset isn't failing it has several values

Comment: Since you are using some print statements, can you elaborate up to which print statement your code executes without problems?

Comment: @petkostas I found the line it is erroring on and added it to the answer

Comment: @Atma: post your urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are never returning a `HttpResponse` in your view.

Try this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        print 'in post'
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, question_id=question.id)
        print '---'
        options = request.POST.getlist('options')
        option = options[0]
        print option
        if form.is_valid():
            print '******'
            print form
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
 else:
     form=QuestionForm()
     return render(request,'myapp/form.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1):

When overriding the `clean()` method, you should be using `super()`.  This calls the inherited functionality of `clean()`. So your form should look something like this:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    # for logic
    def clean(self):
        super(QuestionForm, self).clean()
        # get the initial 'cleaned_data' Dict from the form
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        # clean it however you wish, just make sure to return it at the end of clean()
        return cleaned_data
```

Also as "brain storm" said above, views have to return `Http Responses`.